# Apply mappings in ElasticSearch 7

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping, logstash, logstash-configuration

I have been using ElasticSearch 6 for a long time and managed to apply a mapping for my most used fields. Recently, I've created another cluster (v7.7), but cannot apply the same mappings as the *default* has been deprecated. I have some nested objects in my mappings. When I replace *default* with _doc, I can apply the mapping, however all the incoming requests to ES will be rejected and will go to Logstash dead letter queue. (I'm using logstash and sending my application logs to ElasticSearch. Here is my mapping json:

```
  "index_patterns": [
    "logstash-*"
  ],
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "mapping": {
        "total_fields": {
          "limit": "50000"
        }
      },
      "refresh_interval": "5s"
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "_default_": {
      "_all": {
        "norms": false
      },
      "properties": {
        "@timestamp": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "name": {
          "ignore_above": 64,
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "logger": {
          "ignore_above": 64,
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "hostname": {
          "ignore_above": 256,
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "pid": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "level": {
          "type": "short"
        },
        "v": {
          "type": "short"
        },
        "env": {
          "ignore_above": 64,
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "service": {
          "ignore_above": 256,
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "message": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "module": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "subModule": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "docker": {
          "properties": {
            "container_id": {
              "ignore_above": 512,
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "container_name": {
              "ignore_above": 512,
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "image_id": {
              "ignore_above": 512,
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "image_name": {
              "ignore_above": 512,
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "command": {
              "ignore_above": 512,
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "tag": {
              "ignore_above": 512,
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "created": {
              "type": "date"
            }
          }
        },
        "data": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "context": {
          "properties": {
            "trade": {
              "properties": {
                "id": {
                  "ignore_above": 64,
                  "type": "keyword"
                }
              }
            },
            "trader": {
              "properties": {
                "id": {
                  "ignore_above": 64,
                  "type": "keyword"
                },
                "email": {
                  "ignore_above": 1024,
                  "type": "keyword"
                }
              }
            },
            "payment": {
              "properties": {
                "id": {
                  "ignore_above": 64,
                  "type": "keyword"
                }
              }
            },
            "err": {
              "properties": {
                "message": {
                  "type": "text"
                },
                "name": {
                  "ignore_above": 256,
                  "type": "keyword"
                },
                "stack": {
                  "type": "text"
                },
                "code": {
                  "ignore_above": 256,
                  "type": "keyword"
                },
                "file": {
                  "ignore_above": 256,
                  "type": "keyword"
                },
                "line": {
                  "type": "integer"
                },
                "cause": {
                  "properties": {
                    "message": {
                      "type": "text"
                    },
                    "name": {
                      "ignore_above": 256,
                      "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "stack": {
                      "type": "text"
                    },
                    "code": {
                      "ignore_above": 256,
                      "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "file": {
                      "ignore_above": 256,
                      "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "line": {
                      "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "cause": {
                      "properties": {
                        "message": {
                          "type": "text"
                        },
                        "name": {
                          "ignore_above": 256,
                          "type": "keyword"
                        },
                        "stack": {
                          "type": "text"
                        },
                        "code": {
                          "ignore_above": 256,
                          "type": "keyword"
                        },
                        "file": {
                          "ignore_above": 256,
                          "type": "keyword"
                        },
                        "line": {
                          "type": "integer"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "req": {
              "properties": {
                "id": {
                  "ignore_above": 64,
                  "type": "keyword"
                },
                "remoteAddress": {
                  "type": "ip"
                },
                "remotePort": {
                  "type": "integer"
                },
                "method": {
                  "ignore_above": 32,
                  "type": "keyword"
                },
                "path": {
                  "type": "text"
                },
                "body": {
                  "type": "text"
                },
                "bodyLength": {
                  "type": "integer"
                },
                "headers": {
                  "type": "text"
                }
              }
            },
            "res": {
              "properties": {
                "statusCode": {
                  "type": "short"
                },
                "body": {
                  "type": "text"
                },
                "bodyLength": {
                  "type": "integer"
                },
                "headers": {
                  "type": "text"
                },
                "latency": {
                  "type": "integer"
                }
              }
            },
            "event": {
              "properties": {
                "eventName": {
                  "ignore_above": 256,
                  "type": "keyword"
                },
                "context": {
                  "type": "text"
                },
                "uuid": {
                  "ignore_above": 64,
                  "type": "keyword"
                },
                "time": {
                  "type": "long"
                },
                "attempts": {
                  "type": "short"
                }
              }
            },
            "task": {
              "properties": {
                "taskName": {
                  "ignore_above": 256,
                  "type": "keyword"
                },
                "context": {
                  "type": "text"
                },
                "uuid": {
                  "ignore_above": 64,
                  "type": "keyword"
                },
                "time": {
                  "type": "long"
                },
                "attempts": {
                  "type": "short"
                },
                "origin": {
                  "ignore_above": 128,
                  "type": "keyword"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "dlq": {
          "properties": {
            "eventFields": {
              "type": "text"
            },
            "reason": {
              "type": "text"
            }
          }
        },
        "tags": {
          "ignore_above": 1024,
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "type": {
          "ignore_above": 1024,
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm wondering how can I apply this to elasticSearch7?

Here is the ElasticSearch error:

```
[o.e.a.a.i.m.p.TransportPutMappingAction] [0c85334cb2d41154383d0174502e13f2] failed to put mappings on indices [[[__PATH__]]], type [logs]
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Rejecting mapping update to [logstash-2020.10.02] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: [_doc, logs]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer!

Logstash sends the logs to ElasticSearch with type **logs**. Replacing the *default* with logs fixed the issue. However, for applying the mappings in version7, you need to use `PUT /_template/template_1?include_type_name=true`

Answer (score 1):

The answer given by @YLR is almost correct, but there are some parsing errors in the mapping provided by him.

[_all field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/mapping-all-field.html) is deprecated in 6.0

> _all may no longer be enabled for indices created in 6.0+, use a custom field and the mapping copy_to parameter

Refer to this [Elasticsearch documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html), to know more about this.

> Indices created in Elasticsearch 7.0.0 or later no longer accept a
> *default* mapping. Indices created in 6.x will continue to function as before in Elasticsearch 6.x. Types are deprecated in APIs in 7.0, with
> breaking changes to the index creation, put mapping, get mapping, put
> template, get template and get field mappings APIs.

The modified mapping is :

```
{
  "index_patterns": [
    "logstash-*"
  ],
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "mapping": {
        "total_fields": {
          "limit": "50000"
        }
      },
      "refresh_interval": "5s"
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "@timestamp": {
        "type": "date"
      },
      "name": {
        "ignore_above": 64,
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "logger": {
        "ignore_above": 64,
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "hostname": {
        "ignore_above": 256,
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "pid": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "level": {
        "type": "short"
      },
      "v": {
        "type": "short"
      },
      "env": {
        "ignore_above": 64,
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "service": {
        "ignore_above": 256,
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "message": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "module": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "subModule": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "docker": {
        "properties": {
          "container_id": {
            "ignore_above": 512,
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "container_name": {
            "ignore_above": 512,
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "image_id": {
            "ignore_above": 512,
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "image_name": {
            "ignore_above": 512,
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "command": {
            "ignore_above": 512,
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "tag": {
            "ignore_above": 512,
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "created": {
            "type": "date"
          }
        }
      },
      "data": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "context": {
        "properties": {
          "trade": {
            "properties": {
              "id": {
                "ignore_above": 64,
                "type": "keyword"
              }
            }
          },
          "trader": {
            "properties": {
              "id": {
                "ignore_above": 64,
                "type": "keyword"
              },
              "email": {
                "ignore_above": 1024,
                "type": "keyword"
              }
            }
          },
          "payment": {
            "properties": {
              "id": {
                "ignore_above": 64,
                "type": "keyword"
              }
            }
          },
          "err": {
            "properties": {
              "message": {
                "type": "text"
              },
              "name": {
                "ignore_above": 256,
                "type": "keyword"
              },
              "stack": {
                "type": "text"
              },
              "code": {
                "ignore_above": 256,
                "type": "keyword"
              },
              "file": {
                "ignore_above": 256,
                "type": "keyword"
              },
              "line": {
                "type": "integer"
              },
              "cause": {
                "properties": {
                  "message": {
                    "type": "text"
                  },
                  "name": {
                    "ignore_above": 256,
                    "type": "keyword"
                  },
                  "stack": {
                    "type": "text"
                  },
                  "code": {
                    "ignore_above": 256,
                    "type": "keyword"
                  },
                  "file": {
                    "ignore_above": 256,
                    "type": "keyword"
                  },
                  "line": {
                    "type": "integer"
                  },
                  "cause": {
                    "properties": {
                      "message": {
                        "type": "text"
                      },
                      "name": {
                        "ignore_above": 256,
                        "type": "keyword"
                      },
                      "stack": {
                        "type": "text"
                      },
                      "code": {
                        "ignore_above": 256,
                        "type": "keyword"
                      },
                      "file": {
                        "ignore_above": 256,
                        "type": "keyword"
                      },
                      "line": {
                        "type": "integer"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "req": {
            "properties": {
              "id": {
                "ignore_above": 64,
                "type": "keyword"
              },
              "remoteAddress": {
                "type": "ip"
              },
              "remotePort": {
                "type": "integer"
              },
              "method": {
                "ignore_above": 32,
                "type": "keyword"
              },
              "path": {
                "type": "text"
              },
              "body": {
                "type": "text"
              },
              "bodyLength": {
                "type": "integer"
              },
              "headers": {
                "type": "text"
              }
            }
          },
          "res": {
            "properties": {
              "statusCode": {
                "type": "short"
              },
              "body": {
                "type": "text"
              },
              "bodyLength": {
                "type": "integer"
              },
              "headers": {
                "type": "text"
              },
              "latency": {
                "type": "integer"
              }
            }
          },
          "event": {
            "properties": {
              "eventName": {
                "ignore_above": 256,
                "type": "keyword"
              },
              "context": {
                "type": "text"
              },
              "uuid": {
                "ignore_above": 64,
                "type": "keyword"
              },
              "time": {
                "type": "long"
              },
              "attempts": {
                "type": "short"
              }
            }
          },
          "task": {
            "properties": {
              "taskName": {
                "ignore_above": 256,
                "type": "keyword"
              },
              "context": {
                "type": "text"
              },
              "uuid": {
                "ignore_above": 64,
                "type": "keyword"
              },
              "time": {
                "type": "long"
              },
              "attempts": {
                "type": "short"
              },
              "origin": {
                "ignore_above": 128,
                "type": "keyword"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "dlq": {
        "properties": {
          "eventFields": {
            "type": "text"
          },
          "reason": {
            "type": "text"
          }
        }
      },
      "tags": {
        "ignore_above": 1024,
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "type": {
        "ignore_above": 1024,
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @ahmokhtari which are the nested fields in your mapping, which you have mentioned in the question?

Comment: Thanks @Bhavya, but as I mentioned I already tried to remove _default_ without no success. As you can see in the template, there are other types like "docker", "event", "task" which I'm not sure what should I do with them?

Comment: @ahmokhtari Are `docker`, `event`, `task` fields are of nested type ? I mean do you want these fields to be of nested type about which you were referring in your question?

Comment: Well, they're not nested, but my most used fields I can say. My question is, how can I modify them to make this template work?

Comment: I already applied your provided template @Bhavya, but it doesn't go through meaning ElasticSearch rejects all the incoming requests.

Comment: @ahmokhtari As elasticsearch is rejecting the incoming request, so could you please share the elasticsearch logs as well ?

Answer (score 0):

You must update some field that doesn't been supporte in v7.

This request is an example with remove / update unsupported field :

```
PUT _index_template/template_1 
{
 "index_patterns": [
    "logstash-*"
  ],
    "template": {

  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "mapping": {
        "total_fields": {
          "limit": "50000"
        }
      },
      "refresh_interval": "5s"
    }
  },
  "mappings": {

      "properties": {
        "@timestamp": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "name": {
          "ignore_above": 64,
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "logger": {
          "ignore_above": 64,
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "hostname": {
          "ignore_above": 256,
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "pid": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "level": {
          "type": "short"
        },
        "v": {
          "type": "short"
        },
        "env": {
          "ignore_above": 64,
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "service": {
          "ignore_above": 256,
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "message": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "module": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "subModule": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "docker": {
          "properties": {
            "container_id": {
              "ignore_above": 512,
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "container_name": {
              "ignore_above": 512,
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "image_id": {
              "ignore_above": 512,
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "image_name": {
              "ignore_above": 512,
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "command": {
              "ignore_above": 512,
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "tag": {
              "ignore_above": 512,
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "created": {
              "type": "date"
            }
          }
        },
        "data": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "context": {
          "properties": {
            "trade": {
              "properties": {
                "id": {
                  "ignore_above": 64,
                  "type": "keyword"
                }
              }
            },
            "trader": {
              "properties": {
                "id": {
                  "ignore_above": 64,
                  "type": "keyword"
                },
                "email": {
                  "ignore_above": 1024,
                  "type": "keyword"
                }
              }
            },
            "payment": {
              "properties": {
                "id": {
                  "ignore_above": 64,
                  "type": "keyword"
                }
              }
            },
            "err": {
              "properties": {
                "message": {
                  "type": "text"
                },
                "name": {
                  "ignore_above": 256,
                  "type": "keyword"
                },
                "stack": {
                  "type": "text"
                },
                "code": {
                  "ignore_above": 256,
                  "type": "keyword"
                },
                "file": {
                  "ignore_above": 256,
                  "type": "keyword"
                },
                "line": {
                  "type": "integer"
                },
                "cause": {
                  "properties": {
                    "message": {
                      "type": "text"
                    },
                    "name": {
                      "ignore_above": 256,
                      "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "stack": {
                      "type": "text"
                    },
                    "code": {
                      "ignore_above": 256,
                      "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "file": {
                      "ignore_above": 256,
                      "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "line": {
                      "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "cause": {
                      "properties": {
                        "message": {
                          "type": "text"
                        },
                        "name": {
                          "ignore_above": 256,
                          "type": "keyword"
                        },
                        "stack": {
                          "type": "text"
                        },
                        "code": {
                          "ignore_above": 256,
                          "type": "keyword"
                        },
                        "file": {
                          "ignore_above": 256,
                          "type": "keyword"
                        },
                        "line": {
                          "type": "integer"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "req": {
              "properties": {
                "id": {
                  "ignore_above": 64,
                  "type": "keyword"
                },
                "remoteAddress": {
                  "type": "ip"
                },
                "remotePort": {
                  "type": "integer"
                },
                "method": {
                  "ignore_above": 32,
                  "type": "keyword"
                },
                "path": {
                  "type": "text"
                },
                "body": {
                  "type": "text"
                },
                "bodyLength": {
                  "type": "integer"
                },
                "headers": {
                  "type": "text"
                }
              }
            },
            "res": {
              "properties": {
                "statusCode": {
                  "type": "short"
                },
                "body": {
                  "type": "text"
                },
                "bodyLength": {
                  "type": "integer"
                },
                "headers": {
                  "type": "text"
                },
                "latency": {
                  "type": "integer"
                }
              }
            },
            "event": {
              "properties": {
                "eventName": {
                  "ignore_above": 256,
                  "type": "keyword"
                },
                "context": {
                  "type": "text"
                },
                "uuid": {
                  "ignore_above": 64,
                  "type": "keyword"
                },
                "time": {
                  "type": "long"
                },
                "attempts": {
                  "type": "short"
                }
              }
            },
            "task": {
              "properties": {
                "taskName": {
                  "ignore_above": 256,
                  "type": "keyword"
                },
                "context": {
                  "type": "text"
                },
                "uuid": {
                  "ignore_above": 64,
                  "type": "keyword"
                },
                "time": {
                  "type": "long"
                },
                "attempts": {
                  "type": "short"
                },
                "origin": {
                  "ignore_above": 128,
                  "type": "keyword"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "dlq": {
          "properties": {
            "eventFields": {
              "type": "text"
            },
            "reason": {
              "type": "text"
            }
          }
        },
        "tags": {
          "ignore_above": 1024,
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "type": {
          "ignore_above": 1024,
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
  }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks YLR, but as I mentioned I already tried to remove _default_ without no success. As you can see in the template, there are other types like "docker", "event", "task" which I'm not sure what should I do with them?

Comment: I guess, one solution it could be to put 1 indice by "object" like docker / event / task, it looks functionnaly correct, but it depends of your use cases

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch 7.0 using php 7.4 version.
TO mapping the database table in Elasticsearch 7.0 in server

```
<?php
    require 'includes/config.php';
    require 'includes/connection.php';
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';

    class SearchElastic {
        
        private $elasticclient = null;
        
        public function __construct(){
            $db = new Connection();
            $this->con = $db->connect();
            //echo "<pre>";print_r($this->con); die;
            
            $elasticUrls = 'http://'.ELASTICSEARCH_HOST.':'.ELASTICSEARCH_PORT; 
            $hosts = [$elasticUrls];                                 // SSL to localhost
            
            $this->elasticclient = Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder::create()->setHosts($hosts)->build();
            //echo "<pre>"; print_r($this->elasticclient); die;
        }
        
        public function Mapping(){
            $params = ['index' => 'employee'];
            $response = $this->elasticclient->indices()->delete($params);
            $params = [
                'index' => 'employee',
                'body' => [     
                    'products' => [             
                        'mappings' => [             
                            'properties' => [
                                'code' => [
                                    'type' => 'integer'
                                ],
                                'name' => [
                                    'type' => 'text'
                                ],
                                'created_at' => [
                                    'type' => 'text'
                                ],
                                'last_updated' => [
                                    'type' => 'text'
                                ],
                                'rank' => [
                                    'type' => 'integer'
                                ],                      
                            ]   
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ];
            //echo "<pre>"; print_r($params); die;
            $this->elasticclient->indices()->create($params);
            //echo "<pre>"; print_r($var); die;
        }
        
        public function Search($query){
            $client = $this->elasticclient;
            $result = array();

            $i = 0;

            $params = [
                'index' => 'employee',
                'type'  => 'doc',
                'body'  => [
                    'query' => [
                        'match' => ['name' => $query],
                    ],
                    'size' => 9,
                    'sort' => [
                        ['rank' =>  'desc'],
                    ],
                ],
            ];
            
            $query = $client->search($params);
            //echo "<pre>"; print_r($query);die;
            $hits  = sizeof($query['hits']['hits']);
            $hit   = $query['hits']['hits'];
            
            $result['searchfound'] = $hits;
            while ($i < $hits) {

                $result['result'][$i] = $query['hits']['hits'][$i]['_source'];

                $i++;
            }

            return  $result;
        }
        
        public function InsertData(){
            $this->Mapping();   
            $client = $this->elasticclient;
            $stmt = "SELECT * FROM `table_name` where id=1";
            $result = $this->con->query($stmt);
            
            $params = null;
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                $params['body'][] = array(
                  'index' => array(
                    '_index' => 'employee',
                    '_type'  => 'doc',
                    '_id'    => $row['id'],
                  ) ,
                );
                $params['body'][] = [
                    'id'           => $row['id'],
                    'name'         => $row['name'],
                    'created_at'   => $row['created_at'],
                    'last_updated' => $row['last_updated'],
                    'rank'         => $row['rank'],
                ];          
            }
                
            $responses = $client->bulk($params);
            //echo "<pre>"; print_r($responses); die;
            return true;
            
        }
        
        public function UpdateData(){      
            $client = $this->elasticclient;
            $stmt = "SELECT * FROM `table_name` limit 1, 100";
            $result = $this->con->query($stmt);
            
            $params = null;
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){  
                $params['body'][] = array(
                  'index' => array(
                    '_index' => 'employee',
                    '_type' => 'doc',
                    '_id' => $row['id'],
                  ) ,
                );
                $params['body'][] = [
                    'id'           => $row['id'],
                    'name'         => $row['name'],
                    'created_at'   => $row['created_at'],
                    'last_updated' => $row['last_updated'],
                    'rank'         => $row['rank'],
                ];
                
            }
            
            $responses = $client->bulk($params);
            //echo "<pre>"; print_r($responses); die;
            return true;
        }
    }
?>
```